# Disadvantages of using exec command in php script

Tags: php, background, exec, suspend, server-load

In PHP,

```
 I need to execute background tasks. So I have three choices to run script from 
 following commands:

 1)exec
 2)shell_exec
 3)passthru

 I randomly decided to use exec command in PHP.
 Because All of these have similar characteristics.
```

Now I want to know that Is there any `disadvantage of exec() command` which will run in background ? Actually I am not much aware about this command.

Is It make **separate thread from main thread** ? If `yes then`,Is there any way to **clean up or suspend this background thread** ?or `it simply forget it after firing the command`?

I am asking this because in my code there is need to `run this script very fast one after one within moments`. **So Is it create any server load ?**

**EDIT :**
I am using exec command like this :

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

Please guide me on this.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the kind of call you make if `exec()` will wait for the command to finish or not. Of course, running a lot of background threads on a server could potentially create lots of CPU load.

Now, normally any command you run with `exec()` will NOT be run in background, that means your PHP script will wait until the command finishes executing.
In order to have your commands run in background, you have to redirect its output stream and tell it explicitly to run in background by adding this to your command:

```
> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Of course the downside of this will be that you can never retrieve any results from your commands back to PHP. It will be fire and forget.

Comment: Ok.I am using like this only.Please see my edited question.The only difference is that I am using /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 & instead of  /dev/null 2>/dev/null &. Is it take time If I print log into log_file? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you run a PHP script from PHP using exec()? Why don't you just include the file? Anyways, redirecting output to a file will also help.

Comment: Because,I am sending APNS push notification by including another file in Notification.php

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can I use "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" with exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &")  so that no log will be printed?

Comment: I answered your question, please either accept or downvote my answer, but asking a lot of follow-up questions isn't very polite on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

for you redirect both standard output and error output to file, I don't think there are any problems whether you use exec or shell_exec or passthru here.
as far as I know  these are their major diffrences
shell_exec(): return the whole standard out put (it would not show anything on the terminal)
exec(): the same whith shel_exec(), but it juset return the last line of standard output
passthru(): this is like to call the command, it would show the output on the terminal instead of returning it.